# Why does some JSON arrays have brackets in values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have two different JSON responses from `ebay();` and `etsy();`
Etsy JSON array: `[{"listing_id":123,"title":"etsy","..."}]`
Ebay JSON array: `[{"itemId":["123"],"title":["ebay"],..,}]`
[Full Ebay and Etsy JSON result shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUriY.jpg)
**Question:**
1. Why  are there brackets over the values of the key itemID?
2. Is it possible to combine the two arrays and display it together? Will there be additional steps to retrieve the values with/without brackets?

Comment: 1. Because those values are arrays for whatever reason. 2. Yes, yes.

Comment: You can get help from  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_syntax.htm

Answer (score 5):

Etsy JSON array: `[{"listing_id":123,"title":"etsy","..."}]`
Here, listing_id = Integer and title = String

Ebay JSON array: `[{"itemId":["123"],"title":["ebay"],..,}]`
Here, itemId = array of string and title = array of string

So answer your question,

1. itemId is an array of string that's why it is there are brackets over the value.
2. Yes, it is possible to combine two arrays. You need to create the new structure to store the common values.

Answer (score 1):

**Accessing nested data structures**

A nested data structure is an array or object which refers to other arrays or objects, i.e. its values are arrays or objects. Such structures can be accessed by consecutively applying dot or bracket notation.

Here is an example:

```
const data = {
code: 42,
items: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bar'
}]
```

};

Let's assume we want to access the name of the second item.

Here is how we can do it step-by-step:

As we can see data is an object, hence we can access its properties using dot notation. The items property is accessed as follows:

```
data.items
```

The value is an array, to access its second element, we have to use bracket notation:

```
data.items[1]
```

This value is an object and we use dot notation again to access the name property. So we eventually get:

```
const item_name = data.items[1].name;
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON Format follow some notations. In Json **[]** represents list of values or array of values have index in sequence 0 to length of array, **{}** also contains array of values but here index is called as key and these keys are any kind of string or random number.

Here in question `"itemId":["123"],"title":["ebay"]` values of both itemid and title are list of values. So while accessing you need to specify which value you need to display. like **itemId[0]** which return first value. In case no list of values you can directly access it using `itemId`.

Yes you can combine 2 array and display together. It depends on your logic of combine.

Example:-

```
Etag = [{"listing_id":123,"title":"etsy","..."}]
Access It as:-
Etag[0].listing_id #123
Etag[0].title #etsy

Etag = [{"listing_id":[123],"title":["etsy"],"..."}]
Access It as:-
Etag[0].listing_id[0] #123
Etag[0].title[0] #etsy
```